# How to get the confusion matrix and algorithm score from sklearn's isolation forrest

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a csv file with 10.000 entries and 4 columns. I need to detect the outliers in this data and I am using Sklearn's isolation forest. I get decent results, but I have no idea how to print/calculate the score(between 0.0 and 1.0) and also draw the confusion matrix. I will post the code here so you can see my implementation of Isolation forest.

Please try to keep your explanation on a lower level since my skill with Machine Learning is minimal. Thank you.

Also, my code is from a Jupyter logbook so I might have pasted it wrong, but this is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

#Reading CSV
df = pd.read_csv('usecase999.csv')
df.info()
df

anomaly_inputs = ['c0', 'ya0'] #name of the columns, ya0 shows if the value(c0) is an anomaly or not(not reliable enough)
model_IF = IsolationForest(contamination=0.01,random_state=37)
model_IF.fit(df[anomaly_inputs])
df['anomaly_scores'] = model_IF.decision_function(df[anomaly_inputs])
df['anomaly'] = model_IF.predict(df[anomaly_inputs])
df.loc[:, ['c0', 'ya0', 'anomaly_scores', 'anomaly']]

#plotting fucntion
def outlier_plot(data, name, x_var, y_var, xaxis=[0,1], yaxis=[0,1])
    print(f'Algorithm: {name}')
    
    method = f'{name}_anomaly'
    
    print(f"Nr of anomalies {len(data[data['anomaly']==-1])}")
    print(f"Nr of non anomalies {len(data[data['anomaly']==1])}")
    print(f"Nr of values {len(data)}")
    
    g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col='anomaly', height=4, hue='anomaly', hue_order=[1,-1])
    g.map(sns.scatterplot, x_var, y_var)
    g.fig.suptitle(f'Algorithm: {name}', y=1.10, fontweight='bold')
    g.set(xlim=xaxis, ylim=yaxis)
    axes=g.axes.flatten()
    axes[0].set_title(f"Outliers\n{len(data[data['anomaly']==-1])} points")
    axes[1].set_title(f"Inliers\n{len(data[data['anomaly']==1])} points")
    return g

outlier_plot(df, "Isolation Forest", "c0", "ya0", [0, 5], [0,1.5])
plt.show(sns)
```

I did not try yet anything since I do not have a clue on how to access the confusion matrix and the algorithm score.

Answer (score 0):

Isolation Forest is an unsupervised algorithm, which means it doesn't have a notion of true and predicted labels. Therefore, common evaluation metrics such as accuracy score, precision, recall, F1-score, etc are not applicable.

you can use the confusion_matrix() method:

```
true_labels = df['ya0']  # true labels
pred_labels = df['anomaly']  # predicted labels
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(true_labels, pred_labels)
print(conf_matrix)
```

let me know if it's working. Also you can calculate the mean, standard deviation, and the histogram of the anomaly scores:

```
import numpy as np

# mean anomaly scores
mean_scores = np.mean(df['anomaly_scores'])
print("Mean of anomaly scores: ", mean_scores)

# standard deviation
std_scores = np.std(df['anomaly_scores'])
print("Standard deviation of anomaly scores: ", std_scores)

# histogram 
plt.hist(df['anomaly_scores'], bins=50)
plt.xlabel('Anomaly Scores')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

for calculate the AUC using the roc_auc_score() function (you need to have a notion of true labels in your data, otherwise, you can't calculate AUC.):

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

# true labels
y_true = df['ya0']

# predicted scores
y_scores = df['anomaly_scores']

# calculate the AUC
auc = roc_auc_score(y_true, y_scores)
print("AUC: ", auc)
```

Comment: Hey. It is working, thank you so much. For the last part, I do have a column in my data with either a 0 or a 1 as a value. This flags if the value is an anomaly, but this is only test data, since the final data will never have such a column that says if its an anomaly. So the data looks like this: Column1 timestamp, column2(called x0) is the state of the machine(on/off), column3(ya0) is 1 if the entry is anomalous and 0 if not, column4(c0) is the value itself (floats from -5 to 5).

Comment: You can use the classification_report and confusion_matrix functions from the sklearn.metrics module to evaluate the performance of your algorithm. Keep in mind that if you're using a column with known anomalies as your ground truth, it might be very hard to get good results since the model is trying to achieve a very high standard